# Error creating bean with name 'openApiResources' defined in the class path resource 'SpringDocWebMvcConfigure'

Tags: openapi, spring-boot-3

Getting server startup issue with spring boot 3.2.2 and OpenApi Swagger V3.

`Exception encountered during context initialization - canceling refresh attempt : UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'openApiResource' defined in the class path resource SpringDocWebMvcConfiguration.class: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'openApiResource' parameter 1 : No qualifying bean of type 'org.springdoc.core.service.AbstruceRequestService' available: expected at least one bean  which qualifies as autowire candidate. Depenedency annotation {}`

I am using below openapi dependency: with Spring-Boot 3.2.2 version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And it's causing server startup issue.
Thanks in advance!